# How can i change the subject when forwarding/replying a mail in EWS using c#

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to Forward/Reply to am EWS mail using message-id and not able to change the subject of forward or replay emails.

I have used the below code to change the subject. But the email which is sending will add FW or RE in front of the initial email subject.

`email.Subject = "Sample text";`

**Is there is any code that can change the subject of forward and reply emails?**

Thanks in advance.